# Documents disappear after using the send to function

Tags: document-library, records-center

Documents are disappearing after using the Send To Function.

Our send to function, moves the document from its library, into our Records Centre.  If it has the correct information it routes (using the content organizer rule) to its own library within the records centre, IF it does not have the correct details, it will sit in the Drop Off Library, until it does get the correct properties for routing.

The problem I am now facing, is that when I use the Send to Records Centre function, I get the message popping up saying it has moved to the Drop Off Library, but when I go to the Drop Off Library it is not their, and it is no in any of the other libraries.

Where has the document gone?

I have gotten other staff to test this, to include documents with and without content types, and they are also noticing their documents disappearing.

Please HELP!

I am using SharePoint 2010

Comment: Ok, so I worked out it was pointing to the wrong URL (The Send to Function Link), so I changed it to be pointing to the Records Centre, but now I get this error, when I use the send to Records Centre command:

Comment: The Records Centre site could not be found or accessed.

Retry... 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 7d1be44f-3b37-4495-849d-205c85b7c5d9 

Date and Time: 5/09/2013 6:20:05 PM